# Removing items from custom arraylist implementation

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, data-structures

I'm working on a custom Arraylist implementation and I have one method where I'm trying to remove an item per conditions from an array such as E[] elements. The array is initialized by doing something like this:

```
String[] contents = {"chicken", "hippo", "goat"};
ArrayI<String> newarray = new ArrayI(contents);
newarray.chooser(new LongChooser());
```

It should remove words length 4 or less and return an array like this:
["chicken", "hippo"]

I'm trying not to use any built in methods, like remove(), clone(), arraycopy(), etc. I can't seem to get this to work, I've tried creating a duplicate array and trying to copy elements over like this:

```
 E[] copy = (E[]) (new Object[this.size-1]);

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  if (shorter) {
     copy[i] = elements[i];
  }
  else {
     for (int j = i; j<this.size-1; j++) {
                    elements[j] = elements[j+1];
                }
      elements[size-1] = null;
      size -= 1;
  }

for (int i =0; i< copy.length; i++) {
            elements[i] = copy[i];
        }

        size -=1;
```

I know this is not the correct way because they aren't the same size array and just returns `[longword, longerword, null]`. Also I'm pretty sure I should be using the `size` variable, but it doesn't seem to do much.

How do I get this to work? Thanks.

Comment: What is `ArrayI`?

Comment: The name of the implementation class. Like public class ArrayI <E> implements MyList<E> {